# How can I set height in CKEditor 5 with Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to create a text editor using Ionic and Angular.

I applied it using CKEditor 5 but the height value is not changed.

According to the CKEditor 5 documentation, I can control the height value through the config attribute.

I have confirmed through the config option that 'paragraphs' are translated into Korean.

Is my approach wrong?

Here is my source code.

My source code consists of 'html', 'component.module.ts', 'component.ts'.

html template

```
<ckeditor formControlName="bbsContent" [editor]="Editor" [config]="config" style="height: 300px" data=""></ckeditor>
```

component.module.ts

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
imports: [
   CKEditorModule
  ],
```

component.ts

```
import '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/translations/ko';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

  //ckeditor
export class Classname {
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
  public config = {
  language: 'ko',
  height: 300
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lm7x.png)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [GH issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/36#issuecomment-424081908). Docs on the https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html will be updated soon to cover styling of the Angular component.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The key is "First is via the global stylesheet". but ":host ::ng-deep" is not work for me.

Comment: That's weird. I've checked it and I'm 100% sure it's been working well in my sample app.